# Where's this vantage point on a rock in Charlevoix?

Tags: identify-this, quebec

The screenshot beneath hails from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/kuGzPepBucU?t=326), at the 5:26 juncture.  Where's this?

[image]

Comment: Just a guess from looking at Google Earth: [Mont du Lac des Cygnes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont_du_Lac_des_Cygnes). I can't quite get the landscape to line up with the photo though.

Comment: Did you ask the person who posted the video?

Comment: @MikeHarris Yes. After 2 weeks, I still haven't gotten a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *Mont du Lac des Cygnes* in the *[Parc National des Grands Jardins](https://www.sepaq.com/pq/grj/)*.

If I'm correct, and my memories aren't wrong , it's around those coordinates: 47°39'55.9"N 70°36'11.8"W. It's right behind a security fence that, for obvious reasons of it being a *security* fence, you should not cross ;-) But hey, for a great picture!

I would advice the adventure of going there really early in the morning, at the right time of the year, the sun rises right in fron of your when you're there and the sight is amazing!

While you're around, if you want to hike, my heart goes to the *Acropole des Draveurs* in the *[Parc National des Hautes-Gorges-de-La-Rivière-Malbaie](https://www.sepaq.com/pq/hgo/)*. The sights are to die for (it's the kind you head in the header picture of above linked site), and the feeling of changing biome from a leafy forest to a tundra is one of a kind!